# Reference HTML File Based on Previous Query

Tags: html, pdf, performance-testing, itext7

Based on My Question in the path [iText7 Performance Issue Compared With iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559611/itext7-performance-issue-compared-with-itextsharp) I Have Sent HTML File For MR.Amedee Van Gasse. So Please Tell me How to Improve Performance of iText7..

```
<div id = "headerdiv" style="width:540px; float:left; background:#ededed; padding:30px; overflow:hidden;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>
<img border='0' src='D:\AS1-Revamp\TestHTML\newlog.bmp' width='100' height='40'>
</div>
<p style="color:Red;align=center;" >                         Details</p>
<br>
<br>
<table >
<tr  border='0'>
<td  bgcolor='Green'>
<font size="3" color="white">
SDetails
</font>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr border='0'>
<td>
<div id="dvKYC">
<table  border='1'>

<tr>
<td><#lsName#></td>
<td>No:<#lsno#></td>
</tr> 

<tr  border='1'>
<td width=500><#lsAddess#></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><#lsContacts#></td>
<td> </td>
</tr> 
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>

<div >
<table >
<tr  border='0'>
<td  bgcolor='Green'>
<font size="3" color="white">
Status
</font>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr  bgcolor=gray >
<td style="width:30%;text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">UUH  </td>
<td style="width:20%;text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">PN</td>
<td style="width:20%;text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">KC </td>
<td style="width:20%;text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">CC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  style"width:200px;"><#lsHs#></td>
<td ><#lsPN#></td>
<td><#lsKC#></td>
<td><#lsCC#></td>
</tr>
</table>
 </div>



<div >
<table >
<tr  border='0'>
<td  bgcolor='Green'>
<font size="3" color="white">
STD
</font>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


 <##TT##>


</div>
```

Comment: You should not create new questions if you want to add information. Edit your original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559611/itext7-performance-issue-compared-with-itextsharp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is additional context for a previously asked question.

Comment: ok Thank u for Helping